# Why is the conditional operator right associative?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I can understand why the assignment operator is right associative.  It makes sense that when

```
x = 4 + 3
```

is evaluated, that 4 and 3 are added before being assigned to x.

I am unclear as to how `?:` would benefit from being right associative.  Does it only matter when two `?:`s were used like this

```
z = (a == b ? a : b ? c : d);
```

Then it is evaluated like this:

```
z = (a == b ? a : (b ? c : d));
```

Surely it would make more sense to evaluate from left to right?

Comment: In `x = 4 + 3`, the only restriction on order of evaluation is that the operands of any operator must be evaluated before the operator itself is applied.  Neither `=` nor `+` imposes any ordering on the evaluation of its operands.  For `x = 4 + 3`, the left operand `x` and the right operand `4 + 3` must both be evaluated before the assignment takes place, but that can happen in either order.  Note that evaluating the left operand `x` refers to determining the object to be assigned to.  In a more complex example, `arr[func1()] = func2();`, the two functions can be called in either order.

Comment: Yes, I think I was unclear/incorrect there.  Being right associative means you can do  x = y = 4;  and 4 will be correctly assigned to both y and x

Comment: Just for completeness: If assignment was left associative `x = y = 4` would fail. First, y would be assigned to x and "return" an rvalue with the value of y. This rvalue would then be assigned to 4 which is illegal.

Comment: php is left associative, and causes all sorts of issues. http://www.phpsadness.com/sad/30

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If it evaluated from left to right, it'd look like this:

```
z = ((a == b ? a : b) ? c : d);
```

That is, it would use the result of the first conditional (`a` or `b`) as the boolean condition of the second conditional. That doesn't make much sense: that's like saying:

```
int z, tmp;
/* first conditional */
if(a == b) tmp = a;
else       tmp = b;
/* second conditional */
if(tmp) z = c;
else    z = d;
```

While perhaps one day you'll want to do exactly this, it's far more likely that each `?:` that follows is meant to add more conditions, like `if` / `else if` / `else if` / `else`, which is what the right-associative binding yields:

```
int z;
/* first conditional */
if(a == b)                          z = a;
else /* second conditional */ if(b) z = c;
else                                z = d;
```

Comment: Does right associativity affect the following construction? Or does it not matter in this case?
a ? a ? b : c : c

Answer (score 29):

In any language with a right associative ternary operator, you can stack them and build an if-elseif-elseif-else expression, like this:

```
val = a == 0 ? 1:
      a == 1 ? 2:
               4;
```

On the contrary, in languages with a left associative ternary operator (such as PHP, thanks @user786653) you need to explicitly enforce the aforementioned intent with parentheses:

```
<?php
// This will output 't', not 'true'.
echo (true ? 'true' : false ? 't' : 'f');

// the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');

// here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
// in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
// second ternary expression.
?>
```

Comment: Off-topic, but I can't resist linking to the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) for an example of *left* associative ternary operator.

Comment: I'd say it's perfectly on-topic.  The question was *why* the conditional operator is right-associative (though the OP may not have quite understood what that means).  The PHP example shows the drawbacks of defining the conditional operator to be left-associative.

Comment: I tied to edit your answer to fix the typo, "will output 't" should be "will output 'f'". My edit was held for peer review.

Comment: Why do you think there's a typo? Run the example.

Comment: Can also do a `nested if` too; like for eg : `a > b ? a > c : a : c : b > c ? b : c;` is like `(a > b ? (a > c : a : c) : (b > c ? b : c));`

Comment: Thanks @Bateman, I will use that as my go-to example of unreadable code.

Answer (score 6):

You got the concept of associativity wrong.

When operator `+` is said to be left-associative, this means that `a + b + c` is equivalent to `(a + b) + c`, as opposed to `a + (b + c)`.

The operator `=` is right-associative, which means that `a = b = c` is equivalent to `a = (b = c)`, as opposed to `(a = b) = c`.

Associativity has nothing to do with the order of evaluation.

Comment: "Associativity has nothing to do with the order of evaluation." Well, unless all the operators have the same precedence.

Comment: I was referring to *4 and 3 are added before being assigned to x*. Whether the right hand side or the left hand side of the operator is evaluated first, has nothing to do with the associativity. And no matter if the operator is right associative or left associative, the operands must always be evaluated *before* doing the actual operation.

Comment: You're correct about the addition/assignment thing, and it's good to clarify that bit, but that's not really what the OP's after, and his statement can easily be amended to "I understand why `x = 4 - 2 - 1` returns 1 instead of 3." Nothing you've said so far has anything to do with his question on why `?:` is right associative.

Comment: @Chris: How so?  In `a + b + c`, associativity specifies which operands are associated with which operators, but `a`, `b`, and `c` can be evaluated in any of 6 possible orders.  This doesn't make much difference for evaluating a variable, but consider `func1() + func2() + func3()`; the functions can be called in any order.

Comment: @Keith - I know that, but I don't see how any of it is relevant to "why is `?:` right-associative instead of left-associative."

Comment: @Chris: It isn't -- which is why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer.  It's relevant to your comment, "... Well, unless all the operators have the same precedence."

Comment: @Chris: did you see the question *Does it only matter when two ? s were used*? I think that is a very clear sign that the OP needs some clarification here.

Comment: @Keith - My brain is somewhere else. I still don't undetstand why this answer starts discussing order of evaluation, but when I read that I was clearly not thinking about what "order of evaluation" actually was.

Comment: @Roland - But saying "in `a + b + c`, `a`, `b` and `c` can be evaluated in any order" isn't relevant to `?:` because there's a sequence point between the first operand and the second or third operand. They get evaluated in "the order you'd expect them to."

Comment: @ChrisLutz I believe you used "order of evaluation" in a slightly different way than others to mean evaluation of the expression as a whole to determine the final answer. What others mean by "order of evaluation" is the order in which individual components of the expression are evaluated  at runtime (afer associativity has been determined).

Comment: @ChrisLutz Associativity determines the final answer, order of evaluation of individual components at runtime is non-deterministic.  However once they are determined, they are plugged in and associativity determines the "order of evaluation" of the expression as a whole to get the final answer.

Comment: @RolandIllig It's actually incorrect to say that "in `a = b + c`, `b + c` has to be evaluated first". At the machine level, there are two operands to evaluate: the value to move, and the address to move that value to. `a`, which provides the address to put the sum in, can be calculated before or after the sum. If we replace `a` with a deferenced pointer, and add a side effect that modifies where that pointer points to the right hand side, the order of evaluation can affect the result. Some languages specify the order of evaluation; in C, it's probably undefined behavior.

Comment: @Theodore you're right, and that's exactly why I never said that. And by the way, `a = b + c` is not undefined behavior in C (as that would make the language unusable). It's only that _the order of evaluation is unspecified_. There's a big difference between unspecified and undefined.

Comment: Sorry, rereading your comment, I see you were getting at roughly the same point I was in mine, pointing out that it's the associativity that creates the difference in evaluation order between addition and assignment...sorry for being a bit slow to recognize that. Thanks for the reminder on unspecified vs. undefined.