# Ternary operator within parentheses -- What does this do?

Tags: javascript

I came across some code on an MDN article, and I'm not really sure how to make sense of what it does.

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  curX = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : e.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
  curY = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : e.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
}
```

I'm familiar with ternary operators, but I've never seen multiple "?" used in one line. Can someone explain to me how to evaluate the code for curX and curY? I would appreciate a simple explanation as I'm fairly new, but be as detailed as you want. Thanks

Comment: It's just two ternarys per line

Comment: It does the same thing - `a ? b : c` evaluates to `b` if `a` is truth-y, otherwise `c`. This is an expression, so can be used in another expression e.g. `a ? b : c ? d ? e : f : g ? h : i`; the parentheses just help with readability

Comment: It is a basically like a nested if

Comment: It is essentially a nested `if...else if...else` statement.  Nested ternaries can be pretty challenging to read, so frequently linters will flag them; it trades readability for conciseness.

Comment: It's just a nested conditional operator.¹ If `window.Event` is truthy, `e.pageX` is assigned to `curX`. Otherwise, the result of `e.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft)` is assigned to `curX`. That again involves using the conditional operator to pick between `documentElement` and `body`. (¹ The conditional operator is **a** ternary operator [an operator accepting three operands], and it's the only one in JavaScript **for now**, but it may not be forever. The proper name of `? :` is the *conditional* operator.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do you even read the expression you wrote? Is it from left to right? I'm confused

Comment: Well exactly, that's why it's better to include parentheses!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38875471/3001761