# Operator Associativity and the Ternary Operator

Tags: c++

First, Let me define how I understand operator associativity: Associativity dictates what operation goes first when two operands have the same precedence. If my understanding of associativity is correct, then can someone explain the following:
`std::cout << (true ? "high pass" : false ? "fail" : "pass")`

is the same as

`std::cout << (true ? "high pass" : (false ? "fail" : "pass"))`

Since the ternary operator is right associative, why don't we perform the right-hand operation first? Shouldn't `pass` be printed instead of `high pass`?

Comment: So, particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7407388/2757035) from the dupe.

Comment: Assuming that `false ? "fail" : "pass"` *were*  evaluated first, how could the value of the entire expression be `"pass"`? Are you assuming that determining the value of the inner expression somehow bypasses the outer condition?

Comment: The equivalent using `if` and `else` is `if (true) std::cout << "high pass"; else if (false)  std::cout << "fail;" else std::cout << "pass"; `.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is essentially:

`(true ? "high pass" : (false ? "fail" : "pass"))`

Or more simply, evaluating the conditional:

`(true ? "high pass" : "pass")`

So of course it evaluates to `high pass`.